# android to django - how to authenticate users

Tags: android, django, json, authentication

I'm trying to get json data from a django view (login required)
into a new android app I'm working on.

I would like to authenticate the user against the django login
and keep the cookie/session for all the django view calls to 
get data from the server.

I did some googling but nothing helped me,
even if I guess it should be a quite common task.

Maybe I'm facing the problem from a wrong point of view..
So I'll switch the question to: 
how can I do some user authenticated json request/response to a django server?

Any clue?

Answer (score 2):

You have to do as the website expects, and you need to persist the session cookie.

Answer (score 1):

What I did is using XML-RPC to do all the transfers.
Not exactly sure if it's the best way, considering django's xml-rpc support is some kind of a hack.


Here's a very detailed XML-RPC handler for django:
https://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/XML-RPC

then, setup ur client end on android. 

When communication is okay. Start writing server end API.

from django.contrib.auth import authenticate

and use this function to do authentication.

Then for sessionId stuff, you need to go to backend db to manually do them: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/sessions/


as u can see, this is why I don't think it's the best way. You can't send httprequest, hence most django build-in functions doesn't work.